# onActivityResult changing my current Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment

I am currently having a seemingly odd bug with an application I am writing, this only seems to happen, thus far, on a Samsung S4. It does not happen on an S4 Mini, S5, S6 and Hisense HS-U980. Which is why I am so confused.

I am using a Sliding Drawer system, each menu item changes the current fragment in the Activities container.

This is an example of what happens, I go to Fragment B, I click a button to load an Image using startActivityForResult:

```
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
break;
```

onActivityResult is then called:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if(data.getData() != null) {

                image = ImageTools.copyImage(getActivity(), data.getData());

                int orientation = ImageTools.getOrientationEXIF(getActivity(), image);

                setImage(orientation);

                saveData();

                refreshView();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then instead of returning to Fragment B, I go back to the main Fragment, Fragment A. It also does this with another startActivityForResult call in Fragment C, it too returns to Fragment A.

On the Phones I mentioned where it doesn't do this, it returned to the fragment where the call was made.

Please let me know if you need some more information/code, I am not sure why this seems to happen only on one device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- With a device that your code works go to Settings / Developer options
  and activate the option Don't keep activities.
- Then try to do the same and the problem should also occur in this
  device.

I think you have the code for adding the Fragment A in some method that is executed again when the activity is recreated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh wow, it now does do it on one of the devices where it didn't originally. So I guess the activity is being destroyed on the S4?

Comment: I think it depends on the system memory. If the memory is too small during runtime, the system destroys activities to free up some storage. The memory on the s4 is maybe smaller or more is running in the background

Comment: I have a couple of samsung devices and both of them destroy activities very fast like the one that you have, maybe the samsung software is the reason i don't know. Glad that the answer helped you.